# Based on role push colors in an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 50 roles. Let's say Developer, Manager, Team Lead, Lead Developer, Manager, Assistant Manager, Senior Manager, and so on. Each role has a color.
For example, the JSON is shown below

```
{"Manager":"red","Team Lead":"Orange","Manager":"pink","Assistant Manager":"Yellow}
```

API output looks like this

```
this.roles= ['Manager','Team Lead','Lead Developer', 'Manager']
```

my desired output should be like this

```
 this.colors=['red','Orange','blue','pink']
```

how do I achieve this?

Comment: I understand your problem and some has already answer it but I think you should put attention on your json, you can't have an object with duplicate key... And I see that your "Manager" is write twice.

Comment: Manger wont have 2 colors.I just wrote it for an example.Each role wil have one unique color

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a component, call this function `onInit` to ensure that it will be called before first render.

```
rolesWithColors = {'Manager':'red','Team Lead':'Orange','Manager':'pink','Assistant Manager':'Yellow'};
roles = ['Manager','Team Lead','Lead Developer', 'Manager'];
colors = [];   

ngOnInit() {
  this.findColors(); 
}

findColors() {
  this.colors = [];
  this.roles.foreach(role => {
    this.colors = [...this.colors, this.rolesWithColors[role]];
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const colorsOfRoles = JSON.parse(YoursObjet);
this.colors = this.roles.map((role) => colorsOfRoles[role])
```

I am not sure what you want